# .sh script not writing to file in crontab-e

Tags: shell, cron

Ok, I'm creating a script that monitors MAC addresses on my local network. Everytime I run the script manually it runs perfectly and creates the file `ARPresults.txt` with a list of addresses.

However when I `crontab -e` to automate it, it creates the file but does not write any information to it. I have checked permissions but still it only creates the file, not write to it.

My script is

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    sudo arp-scan -l -r 3 > /home/sam/Linux/wifi/ARPresults.txt
    if grep -q d8:1c:79:68:0a:19 /home/sam/Linux/wifi/ARPresults.txt
    then
        python3 /home/sam/Linux/wifi/send.py
        sleep 12h
    else
        sleep 10
    fi 
done
```

and my crontab is

```
15 23 * * * /home/sam/Linux/wifi/detect.sh
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Issue is you're calling a command with `sudo`. So its probably running, and then waiting for you to type in your password. Since its running in the background, you never get that password prompt. Though you can pipe your sudo password into the command, thats generally a **horrible** idea because youre storing your sudo password in plaintext.

Comment: Append to your cronjob: `>/tmp/logfile.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Add full path to `arp-scan` in your script.

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: and read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info . Good luck.

Comment: @SamWarburton : _it creates the file but does not write any information to_ : I guess you refer to the file `ARPresults.txt`, because this is the only one which we can see in your script being created. The file is created by the shell, and if it is empty, it means that `arp-scan` does not produce any output. You could verify this by doing a `arp-scan ... | tee /home/sam/Linux/wifi/ARPresults.txt` instead.

Comment: @SamWarburton : BTW, I replaced your _bash_ tag by a _shell_ tag, because there is no bash involved in your question.